# How to restore a database from bak file from azure data studio on Mac

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Previously on Mac I use mysql operation studio and I click on database and click restore then browse to my bak file, but now they change to azure data studio and when I repeat the same steps I got this error:
"You must enable preview features in order to use restore" 
[image]
but I cannot figure out hot to enable that. I have googled and tried few things even open my azure, microsoft account on website but I do not see that option. 
Can some one help please !

Comment: A .bak file sounds like it's probably SQL Server rather than MySQL. Are you sure you tagged this question correctly?

Comment: edited, tks for your comment !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Go to Azure Data Studios > Settings
- Edit settings by clicking on
  "new settings editor"
- Search for "preview"
- Scroll to the bottom and
  check "Enable unreleased preview features"

Comment: yes, on Mac I have to click preference\setting then in search box I search : unreleased preview, then in the line of unreleased preview, I click and move mouse to the pen icon and click and choose "true".  Then I can open the restore now, however, when I click on "Restore from" choose Backup file, then "Backup File path" click on "..." but it never open the explorer to browse the file ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding this as an answer as I don't have enough rep to comment.  This is in response to the question in the comment for the answer to the OP (If that's not confusing enough!)

This only applies when your sql database is hosted on a Mac/Linux/Docker Container.  We don't have any Windows servers in our estate for me to test this on to see if the location of the .bak files is any different.

When you click on the "..." button, it browses to /var/opt/mssql/data on the machine (or docker container) the database is hosted on.  This is not an issue if you are backing up & restoring databases on the same host, however, if you're migrating to a new server or just creating a dev/UAT/staging environment, it becomes a problem because you don't have access to var/opt/mssql/data.

This is a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut type solution but as I'm working with 2 dev boxes, it doesn't make a lot of difference to me.

To make this easier to understand I'll call the server that hosts the database you have backed up **ProdServ** & the server you are restoring to **DevServ**.

On DevServ, at a terminal prompt, navigate to /var/opt and make a note of the current permissions on the mssql directory (mine were drwxrwx---).

```
$ cd /var/opt

$ ls -la
```

Google the octal value for your permissions (in my instance, it's 770)

Change the permissions of the data directory to rwxrwxrwx.

```
$ chmod -R 777 /var/opt/mssql/data
```

(You will also need to do this on ProdServ if that is also a Unix-based o/s)

Copy the .bak files from ProdServ to DevServ via a method suitable to the environment you're working in.

Windows --> Linux I'd use WinSCP

For Mac to Docker, `docker cp <fileToCopy> <container>:<destinationPath>` works perfectly fine.

Once the files have been copied over, they will magically appear when you click the "..." button in azure data studio again.  Make sure you change the directory permissions back to their original value via the same command.  So in my instance, simply

```
$ chmod -R 770 /var/opt/mssql/data
```

As an extra note, if you're used to working in MSSMS, the wizard there allows you to create a database from a .bak file, from what I can see, Azure Data Studio does not.  You have to create the database first (`CREATE DATABASE <databasename>`) in a query window, then restore the .bak file to it.

Comment: I got error message this: 'Operation not permitted' when I runned the chmod -R 775 /var/opt/mssql/data

Comment: You may need to sudo the command.  If that doesn't work on it's own, try sudo chown root:root /var/opt/mssql/data then run the chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

simple add this to your setting file:

```
"workbench.enablePreviewFeatures": true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on View at the top menu next to Window.
Then select the first option Command Palette
Then in the command textbox type Restore and select Restore
Then the restore window comes up.